# SMTP - SSL Certificate Issue - C# - Why this code works?

Tags: c#, ssl, smtp

Now, this question has several versions in Stack Overflow like this [most viewed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777607/the-remote-certificate-is-invalid-according-to-the-validation-procedure-using/18796688) in which most of the answers advise the users to turn off SSL as a method to bypass the code.

I was getting the same exception while trying to send email.

> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException:
>   The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation
>   procedure.

This was my code

```
private void sendAMail(String toAddress, String messageBody)
        {
            String msg = "Sending mail to : " + toAddress;

            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.To.Add(toAddress);
            mail.From = new MailAddress("from@mydomain.com");
            mail.Subject = "Subject: Test Mail";
            mail.Body = messageBody;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;            

            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

            smtp.Host = "myhostname.com";            
            smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("sender@sample.com", "");
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.Port = 587;            
            smtp.Send(mail);            
        }
```

While trying several things, finally I tried to print the SSL certificate from the server as mentioned here.[Print SSL Cert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109752/use-c-sharp-to-get-an-smtp-server-certificate/%22print%20SSL%20Cert%22)

Then, the exception is gone.!!! I am not able to figure out why.

This is the code that worked

```
private void sendAMail(String toAddress, String messageBody)
        {
            String msg = "Sending mail to : " + toAddress;

            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.To.Add(toAddress);
            mail.From = new MailAddress("from@mydomain.com");
            mail.Subject = "Subject: Test Mail";
            mail.Body = messageBody;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;            

            //Added this line here
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(RemoteServerCertificateValidationCallback);
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

            smtp.Host = "myhostname.com";            
            smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("sender@sample.com", "");
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.Port = 587;            
            smtp.Send(mail);            
        }


private bool RemoteServerCertificateValidationCallback(object sender, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certificate, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    //Console.WriteLine(certificate);
    return true;
}
```

Please explain me the reason it works while the original code is still throwing exception.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following code is telling your application to trust all certificates, even if they are not valid.

It is best not to do this.

```
private bool RemoteServerCertificateValidationCallback(object sender,
System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate
certificate, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain
chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) {
    //Console.WriteLine(certificate);
    return true; }
```