# Downloading Txt File From Ftp Any Txt File With Out Knowing Name Of txt File

Tags: c#, asp.net

I Want to download txt file from ftp with out knowing the name any txt file is to be download I have a code to download a txt file but am not able to download any txt file with out knowing name pls help me i ll show that code below.

```
    string localPath = @"E:\";
    string fileName = "sample.txt";
    try
    {

        FtpWebRequest requestFileDownload = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://---.--.---.--/" + fileName);
        requestFileDownload.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("----", "----");
        requestFileDownload.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;



        FtpWebResponse responseFileDownload = (FtpWebResponse)requestFileDownload.GetResponse();

        string _filename = "----.txt";

        Stream responseStream = responseFileDownload.GetResponseStream();
        FileStream writeStream = new FileStream(localPath + _filename, FileMode.Create);

        int Length = 2048;
        Byte[] buffer = new Byte[Length];
        int bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);

        while (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
        }

        responseStream.Close();
        writeStream.Close();

        requestFileDownload = null;
        responseFileDownload = null;
```

Comment: So what do you want to download if you don't know the name? Just everything?

Comment: Can u tell me how it to be define before .txt

Comment: Define what? You need to be more descriptive in your question. How to know something you don't know?

Comment: if 4 files in ftp i have to download that files one by one with out knowing that file names

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298922/how-to-list-directory-contents-with-ftp-in-c.

Comment: if any file come to ftp i have to download it that names may change for every file

Comment: i tried that but that code downloading total dir i need a file only if any file come to the ftp that i have to be download in my local dir

Comment: If you have that list, you can determine the files to download yourself, right?

Comment: Yes u r right but i dont know how that name will that comes from various end systems every time that name will be changed am getting trouble with that if difined like *.txt server saying like no file found ..... is it possible or not

Comment: No. Not possible. You have to extract it yourself based on the information in the linked post.

Answer (score 0):

You can list all files in a ftp directory. see [Listing all files from ftp server using C#](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7758e7a8-e063-4eec-a6c1-c76a59d02852/listing-all-files-from-ftp-server-using-c?forum=csharpgeneral)

Sample usage:

```
    Dim FTPfiles = GetListOfFilesinFTPdirectory(FtpDir, ftpusername, ftppassword, New String() {".txt", ".aspx"})
    For Each f In FTPfiles
        Debug.WriteLine(f)
    Next
```

Use below function to list files in a FTP directory. (returns just file names)

```
''' <summary>
''' 
''' </summary>
''' <param name="FtpDir">ftp://------@ftp.domainname.com/www/en/...</param>
''' <param name="ftpusername">FTP user name</param>
''' <param name="ftppassword">FTP user password</param>
''' <param name="fileExtensions">file extension e.g New String() {".txt", ".aspx", ".png"}, Nothing means list all files.</param>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Shared Function GetListOfFilesinFTPdirectory(FtpDir As String, ftpusername As String, ftppassword As String, Optional fileExtensions As String() = Nothing) As List(Of String)

    Dim FTPReq As FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(FtpDir), FtpWebRequest)
    FTPReq.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails
    FTPReq.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(ftpusername, ftppassword)
    FTPReq.UseBinary = True
    FTPReq.KeepAlive = False

    Using response As FtpWebResponse = DirectCast(FTPReq.GetResponse(), FtpWebResponse)
        Using responseStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
            Using reader As New StreamReader(responseStream)
                Dim RawDirectoryListingData As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
                'Debug.WriteLine(RawDirectoryListingData)

                'Windows FTP Server Response Format
                'DateCreated        IsDirectory   Size  FileName

                '06-09-14  07:01PM                39778 MasterPage.master
                '06-09-14  07:01PM                 2806 MasterPage.master.vb
                '09-01-10  01:43PM                 1046 masterpagelink.txt
                '12-29-10  06:16PM                75293 MasterPageTR.master
                '12-29-10  06:16PM                10500 MasterPageTR.master.vb
                '09-01-10  01:43PM                10725 meebotest.aspx
                '01-17-13  03:54PM       <DIR>          mp4player
                '11-30-11  12:40PM                17164 news.aspx
                '11-30-11  12:40PM                 2342 news.aspx.vb
                '12-14-10  10:17PM                12889 news.xml
                '12-14-10  08:14PM                16379 news1.xml


                Dim lines() As String = Split(RawDirectoryListingData, Environment.NewLine)

                Dim FTPFileNames As New List(Of String)

                For Each line As String In lines
                    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(line) Then Continue For
                    Try

                        ''Parse date
                        'Dim DateCreatedStr As String = line.Substring(0, 17)
                        'Dim DateCreated As DateTime = Nothing
                        'DateTime.TryParse(DateCreatedStr, DateCreated)

                        line = line.Remove(0, 24)

                        ' Parse <DIR>
                        Dim dirStr As String = line.Substring(0, 5)
                        Dim isDirectory As Boolean = dirStr.Equals("<dir>", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                        line = line.Remove(0, 5)
                        line = line.Remove(0, 10)

                        ' Parse name
                        Dim fName As String = line
                        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(fName) Then Continue For

                        If Not isDirectory Then
                            If fileExtensions Is Nothing OrElse fileExtensions.Length < 1 Then
                                FTPFileNames.Add(fName)
                            Else
                                For Each ext As String In fileExtensions
                                    Dim fExt As String = IO.Path.GetExtension(fName)
                                    If fExt.Equals(ext, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Then
                                        FTPFileNames.Add(fName)
                                        Exit For
                                    End If
                                Next
                            End If
                        End If
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        Continue For
                    End Try
                Next
                Return FTPFileNames
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using

    Return Nothing

End Function
```