# how connect with ftp from code

Tags: c#, ftp, drive, getfiles

hello how can I replace our ftp to our server  on driver address in this code?

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\MyDir\", "*.bmp");
```

for example:

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"our ftp address", "*.bmp");
```

the first code is running well but second isnt working!?
tnx

Comment: You are using `ftp://` ? If so you cannot use `Directory.GetFiles()` See [How to: List Directory Contents with FTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229716.aspx)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to List Directory Contents with FTP in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298922/how-to-list-directory-contents-with-ftp-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

Example from  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx
DisplayFileFromServer(your bmp file)

```
`public static bool DisplayFileFromServer(Uri serverUri)
{
    // The serverUri parameter should start with the ftp:// scheme. 
    if (serverUri.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeFtp)
    {
        return false;
    }
    // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
    WebClient request = new WebClient();
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential ("anonymous","janeDoe@contoso.com");
    try 
    {
        byte [] newFileData = request.DownloadData (serverUri.ToString());
        string fileString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(newFileData);
        Console.WriteLine(fileString);
    }
    catch (WebException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
    return true;
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

This short program will list the files and directories from an FTP server using the ListDirectoryDetails method. There's also a ListDirectory method that will list only the names.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WebRequest ftp =  FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.ed.ac.uk/");
            ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;
            using (WebResponse rsp = ftp.GetResponse())
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(rsp.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```