# ftpWebReponse (ListDirectory) FTP approved log in process, but not returning folder data

Tags: c#, ftpwebrequest, getresponsestream

I've been experimenting with using Visual C# to connect to a remote FTP server, and list the folders on the server.  Ultimately, I'm trying to figure out how to automatically upload a file to this server with the click of a button.  I figured my first step would be to see how the folders are structured on the remote FTP server.  However, when I try to view the results passed in debug, it appears to be empty, although I didn't receive any errors from the process, and the parameters in debug make it look like I was successfully logged in.  I also received the file transfer complete message 226 in the response data.  Here's the latest code I have tried, although I have tried various things in the FtpWebRequest function.  If I turn off UsePassive, it sits there forever and I never get a response back from the server.  Does anyone have any ideas on a setting that might be causing this or some parameter that might need to be set?

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://sampleftpplace.com/");
        ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
        ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
        ftpRequest.EnableSsl = true;
        ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
        ftpRequest.Proxy = null;
        ftpRequest.Timeout = -1;
        ftpRequest.KeepAlive = false;
        //ftpRequest.UsePassive = false;
        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

        List<string> directories = new List<string>();

        string line = streamReader.ReadLine();
        while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
        {
            directories.Add(line);
            line = streamReader.ReadLine();
        }

        streamReader.Close();
    }
```

When the "string line = streamReader.Readline();" is executed, the variable "line" is null.  All I am really after is to see what folders are available so I can see how the original programmer of the FTP server structured their folders, and what naming convention they used.  Is this possible if that programmer isn't available any more?

Comment: Have you tried to login to the FTP site using a normal FTP client?  It is possible that their is nothing in the root folder, so the list is empty?

Comment: Also, this is a possible dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298922/how-to-list-directory-contents-with-ftp-in-c     You may find the answer you are looking for there.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the information.  I was scouring through that post you referred me to, and was actually where I found the code to begin with.  The main difference is that it requires an SSL connection.  Normally, you have to upload files to the server manually.  You would go to https://sampleftpserver.com.  This would direct you to a log in page.  Once you type your user & password, it directs to another page where you can search for a folder.  I would think that if you logged in through the web request, you would be able to see those folders.  Maybe what I'm trying is impossible?

Comment: Perhaps if you knew the folder that it redirects you to, you could try to login directly to that folder or something.  I'm not exactly sure, it could be a special setup for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to check around here and see if anyone knows anything about it.  It's not that important, but was hoping to eliminate a step or 2 for the end user.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a crazy thought, and it turned out that it worked!  Basically, I changed the first couple of lines to read like this:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("ftp://sampleftpplace.com//");
FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
```

First, I used the command Uri.  Not sure if that matters or not, but what really mattered was the 2nd "/" in the URL address.  I think the server didn't see it as the root directory until I added this.  Once I put that in, I'm seeing the folders now.  Thanks!